# Which of the following is equivalent to the expression? $i^{22}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Which of the following is equivalent to the expression? $i^{22}$

A.) $-1$ 
B.) $i$
C.) $1$
D.) $-i$

What is $i$? How could it have a exponent if it's an imaginary number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand powers of $i$, remember that $i^2 = -1$.  Thus, we have

\begin{align*}
i^0 & = 1\\
i^1 & = i\\
i^2 & = -1\\
i^3 & = i^2i = -1i = -i\\
i^4 & = (i^2)^2 = (-1)^2 = 1
\end{align*}

Since $i^4 = 1$, $i^{4k} = (i^4)^k = 1^k = 1$ for any integer $k$.  This observation allows you to write

$$i^{22} = i^{20 + 2} = i^{20}i^2 = (i^4)^5i^2 = 1^5i^2 = 1 \cdot i^2 = 1 \cdot -1 = -1$$

Comment: It is better to say $i^2=-1$ rather than $i=\sqrt{-1}$... so start with "remember that $i^2=-1$." Otherwise +1.

Answer (score 4):

STRONG HINT:

$$i^{22}=(i^2)^{11}.$$

Because complex numbers can be multiplied together, a definition for $z^n$ is not troublesome for natural and indeed whole number $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$i^0=\color{red}{+1}$$
$$i^1=\color{magenta}{+i}$$
$$i^2=\color{green}{-1}$$
$$i^3=i^2.i=\color{blue}{-i}$$
$$i^4=i^3.i=\color{red}{+1}$$
$$i^5=i^4.i=\color{magenta}{+i}$$
$$i^6=i^4.i^2=\color{green}{-1}$$
$$i^7=i^4.i^3=\color{blue}{-i}$$
$$...$$
$$i^{4n+\color{red}0}=\color{red}{+1}$$
$$i^{4n+\color{magenta}1}=\color{magenta}{+i}$$
$$i^{4n+\color{green}2}=\color{green}{-1}$$
$$i^{4n+\color{blue}3}=\color{blue}{-i}$$

Answer (score 0):

we have $i^2=-1$ thus $i^{22}=(-1)^{11}=-1$

Answer (score 0):

we know $i^2=-1$ so we have that $$i^{22}=(i^2)^{11}=(-1)^{11}=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all the answers so far have used the same reasoning, but I thought of it a little differently. For exponents of $i$ greater than $4$, I usually work out the value of the exponent modulo $4$. That is, $i^n = i^{(n\mod 4)}$.

The reasoning is simple. $i^4 = 1$, so there's a "periodicity" with "period" $4$ as far as exponents of $i$ go.

So the answer here is $i^{(22\mod 4)} = i^2 = -1$.

Just wanted to post this solution so the asker knows a nice general way to approach powers of $i$ from now on.

Comment: IANAMG, but `n (mod 4)` looks odd to me, I would have written it `(n mod 4)`.

Comment: @Alnitak A very valid point. Edited.